# Bounding Box changed position

Tags: adobe-illustrator, bounding-box

Recently in Illustrator I have found that my bounding boxes have changed position!

[image]

I think that I did this with some arcane key combination, but I have been unable to reproduce it. Please see picture for reference. Both positions are admittedly useful, but I lack the option to change between the familiar and the new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find it in **preferences** under general tab, the option in question is called use **preview bounds**.